# Ĉu estas ĝuste, ke oni uzas "paŝtaĵo"n anstataŭ "paŝtejo"?

Tags: word-usage

> 4Kaj ili diris al Faraono: Ni venis, por loĝi en la lando; ĉar ne
>   ekzistas **paŝtaĵo** por la brutoj de viaj sklavoj, (Moseo 1: Genezo
>   47: 4)

Ĉu estas ĝuste, ke oni uzas "paŝtaĵo"n anstataŭ "paŝtejo"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kvankam ne estas efektiva difero, ja ekzistas subtila difero. Kaj „paŝtejo“ kaj „paŝtaĵo“ estas Zamenhofaj kaj ankoraŭ gramatike ĝustaj kaj tial utilaj. Tamen, signife, paŝtejo estas precize ie, kie la brutoj paŝtas, kaj paŝtaĵo estas tio, per kio la brutoj paŝtiĝas, do efektive la sama afero.

Alia maniero, per kiu ili diferiĝas estas la distribuo. Serĉante je Tekstaro.com, mi trovis, ke *paŝtejo* estas ekstreme pli ofta ol *paŝtaĵo*. Fakte, rigardante nur Zamenjofajn verkojn, kvankam ambaŭ aperas, *paŝtejo* aperas dudek fojojn, sed *paŝtaĵo* nur aperas du fojojn, unu el kiu estis la verso, kiun vi citis, kaj ambaŭ estis en la Malnova Testamento. Se rigardi ĉiujn verkojn en la korpuso, *paŝtejo* aperas kvindek ok fojojn, sed *paŝtaĵo* nur ses! Kiel aliaj Zamenhofaj terminaj diĥotomioj (ekz. *pomujo* kontraŭ *pomarbo*), ofte estas historio, kiu elektas kiu vorto estas pli uzata. Eĉ PIV nur difinas paŝtejon kaj ne paŝtaĵon, malgraŭ ĝia Zamenhofa stato.

Resume, ambaŭ vortoj estas ĝustaj, sed *paŝtejo* estas la pli ofta kaj la pli konata, kaj eble la pli preferata.